# Non Stop Loop in Divide and Conquer Algorithm

Tags: r, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I am doing 'find majority element' using R. And when the function me is running, it would not stop and got "*Error: C stack usage  7971200 is too close to the limit*"

I have checked  single majority element comparison and it works.

So which step i went wrong?

```
library(Dict)
maj.com <- function(a,b) {
  if (is.null(a)&& is.null(b)) {
    return(NULL)
  }
  if (!(is.null(a)) && is.null(b)) {
    return(a)
  }
  if (is.null(a) && !(is.null(b)) ){
    return(b)
  }
  if (unlist(a[1]) == unlist(b[1])) {
    a[2] = as.integer(a[2])+ as.integer(b[2])
    return(a)
  }
  if (unlist(a[1]) != unlist(b[1]) && as.integer(a[2]) > as.integer(b[2])) {
    a[2] = as.integer(a[2]) - as.integer(a[2])
    return(a)
  }
  if (unlist(a[1]) != unlist(b[1]) && as.integer(a[2]) < as.integer(b[2])) {
    b[2] = as.integer( b[2] )- as.integer(a[2])
    return(b)
  }
  if (unlist(a[1]) != unlist(b[1]) && as.integer(a[2]) == as.integer(b[2])) {
    
    return(NULL)
  }
}

mydict <- function(key,value) {
  return(list(key,value))
}

me <- function(arr) {
  n = length(arr)
  
  m = round(n/2)
  
  if (n>1) {
    return(maj.com(me(arr[1:m]),me(arr[m+1:n]))) 
  }
  else {
    print(arr)
    
    return(mydict(arr,1))
  }
}
```

Comment: Some test data and your expected output would be helpful. Along with the code you use to call the functions you’ve defined.

Comment: Thank u Limey , I forget to use '()' when  dividing the array